# PHP function to move decimal to beginning

Tags: php

I need a function in PHP to move the decimal to the beginning of the number if one exists otherwise if there is no decimal add 0. to the beginning.

I have:

```
function toDecimal($input){
    return (stripos($input, ".")!==false)? $input: "0." . $input;
}
```

which was provided in a previous question of mine (thanks @shiplu.mokadd.im) but I need to extend it to also move the decimal to the beginning like:

```
Input        Output
0.1234       0.1234
1.2345       0.12345
1234         0.1234
0.001234     0.001234
```

so basically the outputted number can never be larger than 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little recursive magic should do the trick:

```
function divideNumber($number, $divide_by, $max)
{
    if($number > $max)
    {
        return divideNumber($number/$divide_by, $divide_by, $max);
    }
    else
    {
        return $number;
    }
}

// Outputs 0.950
print(divideNumber(950, 10, 1));
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a loop version (recursion was the first thing that came to mind):

```
function divideNumber($number, $divide_by, $max)
{
    while($number > $max)
    {
        $number = $number / $divide_by;
    }

    return $number;
}
```

Comment: Recursion for this kind of problem is pretty much overkill though

Comment: Added another version, for your pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way. Use some math properties - something like this (this will also bring numbers less than 0.1 up front; you didn't specify what we should do with say 0.001234 - if you want to leave numbers less than 0.1 alone, just add a branch)

```
function foo($num) {
    if ($num == 0) return $num; // can't take log of 0
    return $num / pow(10, ceil(log($num, 10)));
}

echo foo(10.23);
```

Comment: He did actually specify that (0.1234 outputs 0.1234) and that no number should exceed 1.

Comment: This works for your input. I mean what about 0.023? Leave it as 0.023, or 0.23? This is fastest, no branches, no loops. Well, if you want to leave 0.023 as 0.023 just add a branch for $num less than 0.1)

Comment: Yes sorry, any number that is less than 1 should be left intact so 0.00000234 should stay as is.

Comment: In [the real world](http://codepad.org/NQBdKIPa) however, it seems that rounding, taking logs and exponenciation is slower than just looping over. Sadly, because math is beautiful.

Comment: @ssice wow - interesting results! Brutal, I finally thoughts logs were useful for something :P